# If Captain Marvel (MCU) were to have a child with a human male, would the child be human or Kree?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019, captain-marvel

If Captain Marvel (MCU) were to have a child with a human male, would the child be human or Kree?

> She was born human but was changed over to Kree and currently has Kree blood and Kree DNA.

Comment: If Carol had her human DNA mixed with Kree DNA (and this is different from receiving Kree blood during a transfusion), then she's likely sterile. An individual that resulted from the mixing of the DNA of two different species is often sterile due to different chromossome counts between these two species.

Comment: Whatever the plot requires.

Comment: Bold of you to assume she'd *want* to make a child with a male!

Comment: what if she had a shild with Thor... oups...

Comment: Demi-god.. Demi-Kree

Comment: Coulson also got blood transfusion from a Kree, but it didn't change his DNA.

Comment: @SatelliteofSin his (Coulson's) DNA might actually *have* changed, as might have Daisy Johnson's or John Garrett's. Anybody who used GH.325 potentially has different DNA.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Whilst the official answer of the MCU is technically "unknown" I would posit that she would have human children.

#### She may not actually be Kree

In the trailer and film Yon-Rogg and the Supreme Intelligence tell her that she is part Kree. However, there isn't really much evidence for this. The main evidence is that she has blue blood but this only came from the initial transfusion by Yon-Rogg to save her. Her *actual* blood may not be blue but they could have been telling her she needed regular transfusions to keep her healthy and thus keep her blood blue.

Of course if she didn't have blue blood, as mentioned by @gowenfawr she would soon find out through her period anyway.

If I remember rightly the only time we see the blue blood is during the fake flashback when Yon-Rogg is replaced by a Skrull. The Kree have obviously manipulated this image so it is likely that  they changed the blood colour. As mentioned by @Anthony Grist later on in the film when she recovers her memory of the events here her blood is red again.

#### Her DNA is almost certainly still human

The only part of her that is Kree, if anything, is her blood. The Kree changed no other part of her per my understanding. Her powers, that the Kree claimed to have given her, actually came from the Space Stone and not the Kree at all.

Comment: @ TheLethalCarrot, well, the only issue I have with that is the rest of her body would have to have been modified to use Kree blood and that probably would have been a DNA change to all the cells in her body. So I would think that she may look Human on the outside but internally all her cells are Kree.

Comment: @HRIATEXP Her body had already been substantially changed after absorbing power from the Lightspeed drive (powered by an Infinity Stone), before she (possibly) received any Kree blood. We also don't know that there would need to have been other changes to allow her to be given Kree blood; maybe the Kree are the intergalactic version of the "universal donor", and it just works.

Comment: From https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kree "Another noteworthy trait is their highly potent regenerative capabilities. Their healing factor is considered to be so profound that S.H.I.E.L.D. attempted to use the G.H.'s blood to perform transfusions with mortally wounded, dying, or dead humans in order to resurrect them or cure them of terminal illnesses.  However, the process only works on beings with "simple" biological makeups like humans". The blood transfusion was to heal her, not to change her to be Kree. They just used it after the fact to pretend she was Kree.

Comment: @HRIATEXP Plus, it's not like humans keep the same blood their whole lives. Blood cells are constantly being replaced by new ones. DNA informs what those cells are. The blast would *have* to have changed her DNA for her powers to last longer than, IDK, a few days? Otherwise she would end up with human blood again after awhile. You can't just "change someone's blood". That's the entire reason blood types must match when doing a transplant. I'm not a fan of this answer. Her DNA is *definitely not* human.

Comment: Who says the Kree even menstruate, when such a thing is rare even in Earth's animal kingdom, which is limited to humans, some other primates, bats, and the elephant shrew. It seems to me more likely the Kree just gave her birth control pills that would stop her from having periods, and lied as to their purpose.

Comment: “If I remember rightly the only time we see the blue blood is during the fake flashback when Yon-Rogg is replaced by a Skrull”. Do we see some in her sparring session with Yon-Rogg?

Comment: I watched the movie specifically looking for Carol's blood and I THINK we see some (blue) during her sparring with Yon-Rogg (from the nose) and while she's escaping from the Kree ship (from the lip). The lighting's a little dark though.

Comment: @Kitkat Re-watching the trailer, and it is dark aye, I wasn't sure if the blue on her face during the sparring was from her powers or blood. Of course that's only a small clip too, I'll have to look more closely next time I get a chance to watch it.

Comment: @only_pro - Exactly. Humans don't keep the same blood their whole lives, and need to replace them via bone marrow. Who's to say Kree blood doesn't self-regenerate (i.e. blue blood cells make more blue blood cells, rather than bone making new cells). Given the nature of the Kree, I'd find it vastly more likely that the blue blood has self-replicating nanites in it that cover the regenerative abilities, or even that it self-replenishes naturally, than the idea that they changed all the DNA in a fully-grown human on-the-fly.

Comment: If we consider the possible spotting of blue blood in the sparring scene as too inconclusive to say for sure, is there really anything to suggest that she ever had any blue blood at all? In the movie at least, the only evidence for this is that she’s been _told_ she has Yon-Rogg’s blood coursing through her veins after a transfusion, but we never see the transfusion take place.

Comment: I thought there was another scene later in the movie (after the first flashback showing blue blood) where she was bleeding red blood. Because I remember thinking to myself "Oh her blood isn't blue anymore, that's odd". Anyways blood != DNA so I agree, there is no evidence that she was somehow "turned into" a kree.

Answer (score 10):

Her children would likely be human.

The Kree do say that she is only part Kree, having been given Kree blood transfusions, just like Coulson and Daisy in the *Agents of SHIELD* universe.

This does not convert them to become a Kree. Her base body and DNA are still pretty much human.

Comment: Please see the comment I made to user TheLethalCarrot.

Comment: @HRIATEXP we have no evidence to suggest that kree blood internally overwrites all living tissue and replaces it with kree tissue. Seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: @Stark07 Please see my comment on the other answer explaining why it would basically *have* to.

Comment: @only_pro It would basically have to iff Kree blood is analogous to a Human blood type. We have no reason to believe this, nor to assume the Kree have the same method for replacing lost or degraded blood cells.

Answer (score 7):

We do see her **bleed blue during the film**. It happens during her memory flashback AND during her captivity with the Skrulls. The Kree may lie to her about giving her the cosmic powers (that she gets from the Tesseract), but they are not lying to her regarding what they have done with her physiology in order to

1. save her life after the accident (she wouldn't survive on Hala without a suit due to environmental conditions alone, for instance).
2. cover up for their grand lie of her being Kree from birth.

Given that she bleeds blue, they had to alter her DNA in order for the blood supply to start replenishing itself as Kree and not human. **Carol Danvers, by the end of the film, is no longer fully human.** This can also be witnessed by the fact that Carol without her cosmic powers can still put up with Kree soldiers because her classic Captain America type powers (endurance, strength, healing factor, longevity, disease resistance, etc.) come from the Kree and thanks to Yon-Rogg.

That is her backstory in the comics, and in an altered way that is her backstory here (instead of DNA mixing you get blood transfusion, and instead of Mar-Vell you get Yon-Rogg).

Most likely, she either would have human-Kree hybrid children (in some respects), or no children at all.

Comment: “she wouldn't survive on Hala without a suit due to environmental conditions alone, for instance” — are we sure about this? Tony Stark, Peter Parker and Stephen Strange survive fine on Titan without any apparent assistance from suits in *Infinity War*. I'm not sure real-world science can reliably be applied to MCU movies. to any great extent.

Comment: @ Paul D. Waite An educated guess, given that this has been made a point of in several comics. If we went by the rules of real-world science reliably then a blood transfusion shouldn't be possible and neither would be a survival after an energy blast from the jet engine. Where the line is drawn in regard to believability is up to  personal preference, I reckon.

Comment: @NargenFlure: I'm not sure the comics are particularly relevant, although I guess they might want to make Hala's suitability for humans a plot point in a future movie.

Comment: Do we have an actual source on her needing to have altered DNA? Given that Kree have remarkable regenerative abilities and a biology obviously at least a little different from Humans, I don't think it's a given that she'd need DNA alterations to keep her blue blood - Kree blood could very well self-replicate or may not need replacement (i.e. exceptionally long-lived, only replaced after trauma).

Comment: ``she wouldn't survive on Hala without a suit due to environmental conditions alone`` but she survives outer space without a space suit?

Comment: Did they also change all existing eggs in her ovaries?